# Codeigniter timespan does not work properly

Tags: codeigniter

My code like below :

```
$post_date = '2017-11-15 21:04:31';
$now = new DateTime();
$units = 7;
echo timespan($post_date, $now, $units);
```

It return me this :

> asked 47 Years, 10 Months, 2 Weeks, 1 Day, 23 Hours, 53 Minutes

where's 47 years coming from?

**UPDATE**

I want to calculate the difference between active time now since he has in the $post_date. For example `$post_date = '2017-11-15 21:04:31';` it's should be 1 day, 8 hours, 9 minutes since he was posted.

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff`.

**Code**

```
$post_date= new DateTime("2017-11-15 21:04:31"); 
$now = new DateTime(); 
$diff = $now->diff($post_date); 
echo "Days: " . $diff->days . " Hours: " . $diff->h . " Minutes: " . $diff->i;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Days: 1 Hours: 8 Minutes: 39
```

**For print_r result**

```
echo"<pre>";
print_r($diff);

DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 1
    [h] => 8
    [i] => 39
    [s] => 22
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 1
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Thankyou very much. Have a goodday.

Answer (score 1):

Epoctime time starts at 1st January 1970 midnight so your function is returning timespan from that date.

47 years passed since 1970.

Clarify what you want to achieve so we can help better.

Comment: Answer by @Bluetree is best solution for your task.